# How to identify a google home (mini) device?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home

I want to identify a google home device via the SDK request / response call to serve the request properly. Basically I need this information to know the location / room / floor / venue where this device is installed or kept.

Example: If I make a request to google mini - "Switch off the lights", I want to know the device id so the service can do a lookup and find the room where this device is located and switch off the lights of that room.

I don't need this for android phones/devices. It is very specific to google home devices.

I have seen `originalRequest.data.user.userId` but not sure if i can use this (as user of the device will not have any google login or account linking)

Is this information is exposed via dialogflow api?

Answer (score 0):

The Google Home device information, including its ID and room assignment, are not available to developers.

This is why the Google Home [Smart Home API](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/) handles most of this for you. It reports exactly which lights are being controlled - you do not need to know which device did the controlling, the Smart Home API tells you exactly which devices are being controlled.

You do not need to use Dialogflow in these cases, since the Assistant does all the Natural Language Processing and simply gives you directions for which devices need to be updated.

Comment: I went through the Smart Home APIs. I understand that these are helpful for targeting. What I want is to find the ID/Name, if any, of the device(let's say Google Home Mini) through the user is giving the command.

Example: I have a Home map of Google Mini and IoT targets. Now I want to execute "Switch off my lights" from Bed room, I want to target IoT device in the bed room. For this I want to know ID/Name (BEDROOM) for the Google Mini generating the intent callback.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've updated to be more clear. As I said - you cannot get the ID of the Home device. The Smart Home APIs tell you exactly which devices are being controlled, so you don't have to figure it out yourself.